# Android record audio get java.lang.IllegalStateException error

Tags: android

this below code is my simple record audio application and i'm try to record audio with microphone. after recording audio i can't stop record and i get an error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException
```

for this line:

```
recorder.stop();
```

My code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    Button startRecordingButton, stopRecordingButton;
    TextView statusText;
    private MediaRecorder recorder = null;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        recorder = new MediaRecorder();
        statusText = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.StatusTextView);

        startRecordingButton = (Button) this
                .findViewById(R.id.StartRecordingButton);
        stopRecordingButton = (Button) this
                .findViewById(R.id.StopRecordingButton);

        startRecordingButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        stopRecordingButton.setOnClickListener(this);

        stopRecordingButton.setEnabled(false);

    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v == startRecordingButton) {
            record();
        } else if (v == stopRecordingButton) {
            stopRecording();
        }
    }

    public void record() {
        startRecordingButton.setEnabled(false);
        stopRecordingButton.setEnabled(true);
        recordAudio();
    }


private void recordAudio() {
    recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
    recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
    recorder.setOutputFile(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath());
    try {
        recorder.prepare();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    recorder.start();
}

    public void stopRecording() {
        recorder.stop();
        recorder.release();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please proivde the stacktrace.

Comment: `setOutputFile(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath());` looks odd. You're not specifying a file name.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are not starting recorder after `recorder.prepare()` that's why you are getting illegal state exception i-e trying to stop a recorder which has never been started.

add `recorder.start()` after `recorder.prepare()`

Secondly, you are also not specifying any output file name,
`recorder.setOutputFile(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath());`

Change it to:
`recorder.setOutputFile(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/recording.wav";`

Comment: now i get this error `java.lang.IllegalStateException` for `recorder.start()`,  post updated,please review again, thanks

Comment: It's not a wav file, but an AMR stream in a 3GP container, so the file ending ought to be `.3gp`

Comment: sure, you can change it to "/recording.3gp" as well